# Loading Times / Breaking points

Tags: web-app, user-behavior, user-research, response-time, browser

We all know that a user is not going to wait forever for a website to load. Given there are certain factors and circumstances that can apply to this, **is there a breakdown of users stages/breaking points that apply to length of time for when loading a website?**

I believer there is the general rule of thumb for the amount of time a user will wait in a content stage, but I was curious to know if anybody could elaborate a little more in the phycology of loading times.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that this has been asked before because there're a few AlertBox articles about this (that's the source of the infographic).

Comment: Related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5529/how-long-should-a-page-take-to-load

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a breakdown:

.1 seconds if you don't want a user to notice a delay, 1 second will give a noticeable delay, but will not affect users experience too much and no feedback will be needed, 10 seconds is the maximum amount of time a user wants to wait without a diaglog explaining what the server is doing and how long they should wait, longer than that and they will loose interest.

According to [this article](http://www.webperformancetoday.com/tag/psychology/) the reason behind it is related to short-term memory not exceeding 15 seconds, so slower than that the user begins to forget what they were doing.

Also, according to [this article](http://www.webperformancetoday.com/2011/02/15/slow-website-performance-customer-satisfaction/) customer satisfaction decresses by 16% for every second they have to wait.

You can speed up a site by reducing image quality, removing flash, or make it more AJAX based.

Visual Break down:
[image]

Comment: I think that's what chester was referring to in his question when he mentioned there is a general rule of thumb for waiting for content. This is the only applicable rule I've been able to find though.

Comment: precisely, I am aware of the more abstract waiting time, I was unsure if there is more of a break down between that .1 seconds and 15 seconds.  I know it is good practice that you should almost entirely not exceed 7 seconds. But there is value to finding those points that lead up to that. Around 3 seconds becomes the agitated state, etc..

Comment: Please read the article and links from it to others and you will find lots of information on it.  I updated it to included more things, but as a general rule every second results in 16% decrees in satisfaction.  The .1 second rule is because it makes the user feel in control rather than the computer.