# Dynamic visuals, loading times and UX

Tags: e-commerce, time

Type of website: e-commerce apparel

I want you to provide my users dynamic visuals such as it gives them an attractive experience. The point is that it takes more time to load.

Do I have to prefer pages loading time or providing an attractive experience on this case?

Example : http://www.jeremyscott.com/
Is it a good balance?

Answer (score 3):

There is a great answer spcifically on how users respond to web page loading times [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22928/loading-times-breaking-points).

For the particular site you linked to, I think the movement on all the items at once is quite distracting, and I would suggest that you limit the moving / animated items to the one that the user is currently focused on (hover for mouse, press for touch devices). Doing it this way also allows you to do some background loading to hide the wait time for loading the whole page.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple issues with how you want your page to display, personally I did not have any load times for the images but I am running on lightning speed internet at my work. The first is that sometimes it appears that one of the images may get stuck and the animation may not kick in so you have all these moving people but then one is standing still. I also have to agree with Franchesca in the below post that all the movement can be quite distracting, perhaps make the image move on hover or after selecting it and moving on to the order page then have the image move. It's not practical to have all of them moving at the same time if they are not being focused in on. Just some suggestions, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The site is of type e-commerce apparel then you can broadly have two kinds of people coming in

1. Who are looking for something (the eager folks): Click url to the site > wait.. > a product or two loads > wait.. > may loose interest and switch to another website. Clearly they never got a feel of dynamic visuals you built for them.
2. Who are just browsing away: Click url to the site > wait.. > a product or two loads > wait.. > may loose interest. Meanwhile if they try to check out other sections of the site (that may not have the dynamic visuals) and it loads relatively faster they may just continue to have a look at things there on till next slow. Or they may also choose to open another website and if it engages them, they might just forget to come back here.

Moral: Dynamic visuals give you an edge when it comes to aesthetics but when it comes to usability you may have to compromise "a bit" of the visuals for ease of use. After all the main aim is that the user stays on your site and checks out whatever you have to offer.